# Como passar o valor de uma posição para uma variável, sendo essa posição recebida em ASCII?

Tags: c#

Então mando um pedaço do meu script para que vocês possam me ajudar. Preciso retornar a variável `rsp`, que vem trazendo sempre o valor igual a 0, o que não era para ser feito.

```
// Envia comando de Leitura de Posição 
serial.Write('R');
serial.Write('7');// controle: absoluto (1) pra cima(1)  e velocidade (3) 
serial.Write(' ');// angulo inicial 
System.Console.WriteLine("Comando enviado.");

// Espera a resposta da Luneta
rsp = serial.ReadChar(); 

System.Console.WriteLine("Resposta recebida.");

//Mostra resposta na Output Window
Console.WriteChar("Resposta: " + rsp);
```

Comment: Aparentemente, seu problema não está nesse trecho de código. Se rsp está com zero, serial.ReadChar() está retornando 0 e isso provavelmente é culpa de algo interno a ela, mas não sabemos o que é serial e nem onde é criada/declarada. Há pouco contexto para entendermos.

Comment: Então Pablo esse serial é uma porta de comunicação entre uma placa de circuito impresso e o pc. de  RS485 para USB.

Comment: então Marconcílio o código serve para movimentar uma luneta onde inicialmente não sabemos onde o ângulo esta, por isso temos um valor da tabela ascii  'R' que recebe essa informação. Esses valores são mostrados através de um display. Inicialmente esse valor da variável rsp deveria ser o valor de 'R' o que não ocorre.

Comment: Obrigada meninos pela ajuda, como o Pablo havia comentado q poderia ser algo interno fui procurar e realmente ele não estava  transmitindo o valor devido e acabei tendo q trocar um pic q estava usando pois ele conseguia receber mas não transmitir.